# InvalidKey at Kraken API with JS, not with Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, fetch, kraken.com

My code to get my Balance from the Kraken API does work in Python (based on the krakenex library), but not in the JS version (based loosely off the kraken-api library, but with the `crypto` library substituted for `crypto-js`). The error is always: **Invalid Key**.

Even when I copy the headers and the nonce sent by the Python client into Postman, I get Invalid Key.

I believe the signature and nonce to be valid, because when they are not, Kraken retorts that either the signature or nonce are invalid.

Is there anything else that Javascript's `fetch` does differently than Python3 `requests`? Because the body and headers are otherwise identical.

JS code that generates auth data:

```
const getMessageSignature = (path, request, secret, nonce) => {
    // API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key
    const message = qs.stringify(request);
    console.log(message);

    const secret_buffer = btoa(secret);
    const hash = CryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create();
    const hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA512, secret_buffer);
    const hash_digest = hash.update(nonce + message).finalize().toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    const hmac_digest = hmac.update(path + hash_digest).finalize().toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

    // CANNOT USE ORIGINAL LIB CODE (Buffer, got and crypto not supported)
    // const secret_buffer = new Buffer(secret, 'base64');
    // const hash = new crypto.createHash('sha256');
    // const hmac = new crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret_buffer);
    // const hash_digest = hash.update(nonce + message).digest('binary');
    // const hmac_digest = hmac.update(path + hash_digest, 'binary').digest('base64');

    return hmac_digest;
};
```

**Update:**
In fact, the following observations are weird:

- correct key + correct signature = "incorrect key"
- incorrect key + correct signature = "incorrect key"
- incorrect key + incorrect signature = "incorrect key"
- correct key + incorrect signature = "invalid signature"

what gives?

**Update2**
Seems the requests are identical (other than the signature and nonce of course, which will and should change with every request).

[image]

Comment: For one, in-browser JS is subject to CORS. Requesting a resource from another domain requires the server to send header information that allows access. For now I'd try and get the Postman request to work, because that's going to be easier.

Comment: thanks. Yes that would be easiest. Although of course, the signature and nonce are calculated dynamically so it requires copying from the terminal each time. I've updated my question with some strange observations while testing via Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the signature after all and Kraken simply doesn't give very accurate responses (which makes some sense, but is a pain if you're trying to figure something out). Finally I was able to rewrite the code using CryptoJS only:

```
const getMessageSignature = (path, request, secret, nonce) => {
    // API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key
    const message = JSON.stringify(request);
    const hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(nonce + message);
    const secret_buffer = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(secret);
    const hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA512, secret_buffer);
    hmac.update(path, secret_buffer);
    hmac.update(hash, secret_buffer);
    return hmac.finalize().toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
};
```

This yields a correct signature and Kraken no longer complains. Zzah.

Comment: hey ! thx for the code sample. I'm trying to used it as a pre-request-script in postman but keep getting the error "EGeneral:Internal error" from kraken. I'm calling your function with
var secret = "mySecretKey";
var nonce = Date.now() * 1000;
var path = "/0/private/Balance";
var request = {};
any idea ? do you have a full working example by any chance ? I would greatly appreciate :) thx

Comment: Hi @salanfe, sure, I just opensourced the Fitbit app I made. Have a look at my codebase at https://github.com/bluppfisk/fitbit-kraken under companion/KrakenClient.js.

Comment: thx ! problem was my nonce in the request body :/ took me a while to figure it out, but it's working